# Rescan Spamassasin Emails marked as Spam

Tags: spamassassin

So, due to issues with an upstream mail server, all incoming emails triggered two rules and got a little over +5 on their spamassassin scores. Nice.

I'm in touch with the upstream provider about getting the issue resolved and in the meantime, I have drastically lowered the score for those rules (to 0.1 each). However, what I now have is a whole lot of emails that are not only marked as spam but have also been wrapped up as nice little multipart-mime messages (which would normally be a good thing, of course).

Now, I've done this the other way, rescanned messages which were not caught by the spam filter and that went fine. However, if I try it this way around, spamc just doesn't bother trying to do any processing. I think I need to pop the original message out of the multipart-mime and then run them through spamc but I'm drawing a blank on how to do this.

Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about doing this?